# Why is Symfony 2 installing all DEV versions of vendor modules?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

So I was trying to install DoctrineMongoDBBundle and part of the instructions it said was to add the following to my composer file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

So I added the above and my composer file looks as follows:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*"
    },  "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Now when I ran sudo php composer.phar update it removed all bundles and installed dev versions of them.

How do I get non DEV versions of bundles except the Mongo bundle?

Comment: Can you show the output of Composer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tag it with `dev`:

```
{
    ...,
    "require": {
        ...,
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
    }
}
```

and remove the `minimum-stability` property, which will default back to stable.

Documentation about this can be found [here](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links).